# selected value from Dropdown of HTML Form does not saves into table

Tags: php, sql-insert, forms

I have an HTML form, PHP file and table on server. after pressing the submit button on form everything is saved to the back table except the SELECTED VALUE FROM DROPDOWN.
[Link to the Table picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AStdO.jpg)

HTML FORM CODE;

```
<form action="personal.php" method="post">
Name: <input name="name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40"><br>
CNIC : <input name="cnic" type="text" size="20" maxlength="15"><br>
Date: <input name="booking-date" type="date" size="20" ><br>
Ocassion: <select name="ocassion" size="1">
<option value="">Barat</option>
<option value="">Walima</option>
<option value="">option3</option>
<option value="">option4</option>
<option value="">option5</option>
<option value="">option6</option>
</select><br>

Address:<input name ="address" type="text" size="20" maxlength="50"><br>
Phone-No:<input name="phone-no" type="text" size="20" maxlength="11"><br>
Bride-Mobile:<input name="bride-mobile" size="20" maxlength="11"><br>
Groom-Mobile:<input name="groom-mobile" size="20" maxlength="11"><br>
Family-Mobile:<input name="family-mobile" size="20" maxlength="11"><br>
E-mail:<input name="email" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30"><br>
Who may i thank for refering you?:<input name="refering" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40"><br>
Do you provide consent to share images on our official web page:<br><input type="radio" name="share" value="Yes">Yes <br>
<input type="radio" name="share" value="No">No<br>
If yes:<br>
With identity: <br><input type="radio" name="permission" value="Yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="permission" value="No">No<br>
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit-Personal">
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="camouflage_studio";

$con = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $con->prepare("insert into personal_detail (Name, CNIC, Date, Ocassion, Address, Phone_No, Bride_Mobile, Groom_Mobile, Family_Mobile,EMail,Referring,Share,Permission) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ssssssiiissss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['cnic'], $_POST['booking-date'], $_POST['ocassion'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['phone-no'], $_POST['bride-mobile'], $_POST['groom-mobile'], $_POST['family-mobile'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['refering'], $_POST['share'], $_POST['permission']);if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
{
echo "New records created successfully";
}
else
echo "Prepare Error: ",$con->error;$stmt->close();
$con->close();

?>
```

Comment: Your option values are empty. That's how they are passed in POST.

Answer (score 1):

Because all values of `ocassion` are  . Change your `option`s like this (or something else that suits you better):

```
<option value="Barat">Barat</option>
<option value="Walima">Walima</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
<option value="option5">option5</option>
<option value="option6">option6</option>
```

Then `echo $_POST['ocassion']` will print one of the values.

Comment: I did the modification as:  Ocassion: <select name="ocassion" size="1">
<option value="Barat">Barat</option>
<option value="Walima">Walima</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
<option value="option5">option5</option>
<option value="option6">option6</option>
</select><br>      but still not working.

Comment: @MuhammadAatif that is weird, it works for me, you can check this working example [here](https://tomudding.nl/tests/stackoverflow/44269087.php).

Comment: i'm also confused :( You popped the value and i'm sending it to the table, but in your case it's working and in my case it's not.......

Answer (score 1):

You have forget the values,
your code is the same:

```
<select name="ocassion" size="1">
<option value="">Barat</option>
<option value="">Walima</option>
<option value="">option3</option>
<option value="">option4</option>
<option value="">option5</option>
<option value="">option6</option>
```

bu there's not the value, probably you might write this code

```
<select name="ocassion" size="1">
<option value="Barat">Barat</option>
<option value="Walima">Walima</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
<option value="option5">option5</option>
<option value="option6">option6</option>
```

Comment: I did as you people guided, but still no success. On another forum I read the same question and the answer was A MISSING SIMICOLON somewhere in the code. I also tried to find out if there's something missing in my code but useless. if one can help,as you have done before as well, would be appreciated. thanks